# Proposed tag changes

Tags: discussion, tags

**Change #1**
I have come across many questions that deal with units, the latest one [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/18071/2217). I propose we change [blender-units](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blender-units) to be [units](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/units). It would fit a broader spectrum of questions, and some that are already  tagged as blender-units are really not about blender-units.
We should also synonymize [measurement](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/measurement) with the new [units](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/units) tag. All ten measurement questions would fit well under *units*.

**Change #2**
We delete [actuators](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/actuators) in favor of [logic-bricks](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic-bricks). I feel there is no need to Synonymize [actuators](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/actuators) as there are only four question tagged with Actuators. Just four little retags and that is taken care of. Not a big change, but I was posting here anyway.

---

**Change #3**
Synonymize [node-editor](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/node-editor) → [nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nodes). These tags seem to be used interchangeably and sometimes both are used on the same post. IMO [nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nodes) sounds like it has a larger scope which would contain [node-editor](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/node-editor), which is why I suggest that they be merged in that way.

Comment: By Blender-Units do you mean the default setup? ie: -1.0, 0.0, 10.0, 20.0, etc. (no cm., mm, inches)
If so, this should definitely be changed.  By adding 'Blender' to 'Units' it gives the impression that there is something Blender-related going on with these numbers when they are just the standard numbers used by people all around the world in every field where numbers are used.

Comment: @MarcClintDion The tag description reads "Basic measuring unit of blender. Acronymed BU. It can generally be held as relative to any unit. Physics engine regards 1BU as 1m." Yes I'm suggesting that we go to just plain units.

Comment: They all look good to me

Comment: Good suggestions, we will try and add a few more to the list and get this done.

Comment: @gandalf3 if this post is going to be continually updated, should we mark the completed tasks as "done"?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe the should be separate answers? I don't know..